# I'm stumped on a simple roman numeral puzzle

Tags: word-problem, lateral-thinking, puzzle-identification

I was working on this puzzle called cupid which listed a bunch of greek gods.  I filled in all the answers in the answer grid which were their roman counterparts.  Since these answers were now left aligned (where the clues were centered) and of course the fact that they're roman gods, naturally I'm thinking roman numerals.  The final answer is a word that can be obtained from these roman gods, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Here are the roman gods:

MARS

CERES

VENUS

VESTA

PLUTO

MERCURY

BACCHUS

Since M,C, and V are roman numerals, I'm assuming that's how to solve it, but I can't figure anything out, and I have no idea where the P and B fit in.  Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong.  Could anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: I'm curious about why roman numerals? I get a roman connection with roman gods but I'm unclear why left aligned  suggests roman numerals (or is that just bad phrasing/reading of that sentence?).

Answer (score 18):

Given that there's little context, it's hard to give a definitive answer, but I'd have to guess that the answer you are looking for is:

> MENTORS

This can be found by:

> Taking the first letter of the first word, the second of the second, etc.